# MySQL replace a row's parent id with another row's post name, in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In a posts table, every post has a parent (parent_id) that could reference another post in the same table, or 0 if it's a first-level post.

In my SELECT clause, **I want the name of the parent (post_name) to display in place of the parent id (parent_id)**

```
SELECT db.id, 
    db.post_name, 
    db.post_type, 
    db.parent_id
FROM db.posts as db
WHERE db.post_type IN ('lesson', 'lesson_content')
GROUP BY db.id;
```

example output:

```
488 gratitude           lesson          0
489 respect             lesson          0
490 consideration       lesson          0
491 stories             lesson_content  488
492 creative-crafts     lesson_content  488
493 parents-guide       lesson_content  489
```

desired output:

```
488 gratitude           lesson          0
489 respect             lesson          0
490 consideration       lesson          0
491 stories             lesson_content  gratitude
492 creative-crafts     lesson_content  gratitude
493 parents-guide       lesson_content  respect
```

What is the best way to go about this, and is there a name for what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a self join then

```sql
SELECT db1.id, 
    db1.post_name, 
    db1.post_type, 
    db2.post_name as parent_post_name
FROM db.posts as db1
    LEFT JOIN db.posts as db2
    ON db1.parent_id = db2.id
WHERE db1.post_type IN ('lesson', 'lesson_content')
GROUP BY db1.id;
```